# How get language details through REST API call?

Tags: java, android

i am developing multi language android app  my question is how to get the language details  through REST api call without using string.xml in android

Comment: are you asking how to determine the device's locale settings?

Comment: No i want language details through rest api call

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you're trying to do. are you saying you want to fetch a locale from a REST API, and then use that fetched locale to resolve string resources manually (rather than using the framework to resolve string resources by device locale)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want get the device current language details, you can use [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale). You can use the following method:

```
Locale locale;
// ctx is your application context
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
    locale = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
} else {
   locale = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}
```

or the following code if you're using Support library [ConfigurationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/os/ConfigurationCompat):

```
Locale locale = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(
                        ctx.getResources().getConfiguration()).get(0);
```

then you can use the following method from [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale):

- `getISOLanguages()`
- `getISOCountries()`
- `getISO3Language()`